# Swift WKWebView goBack and goForward No Longer Work

Tags: swift, webview, wkwebview

I've never seen an error like this before. The below code worked perfectly previously. I don't see any change that I would have made that would change this. Now, goBack and goForward do not work as intended. What happened? This is extremely bizarre.

I have tried tracing this through, all sorts of stuff, and cannot understand why it does not go back when clicked. I even tried adding the webView.reload() after back is clicked, but that does not work either.

I get this error: `Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "(null)"` followed by the page I was trying to visit. Here is my class:

```
class WebPageModalViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mainView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var primaryLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var secondaryLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var backButtonImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var forwardButtonImageView: UIImageView!

    @IBAction func didClickClose(_ sender: Any) {
        IHProgressHUD.dismiss()
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    @IBAction func didClickOpenInBrowser(_ sender: Any) {
        URL.openURL(self.url)
    }

    var url: String
    var webView: WKWebView!

    init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?, url: String) {
        self.url = url
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let backGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer:)))
        backButtonImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        backButtonImageView.addGestureRecognizer(backGestureRecognizer)
        let forwardGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer:)))
        forwardButtonImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        forwardButtonImageView.addGestureRecognizer(forwardGestureRecognizer)

        self.primaryLabel.text = ""
        self.secondaryLabel.text = ""

        webView.scrollView.delegate = self

        let myURL = URL(string:url)
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)

        webView.load(myRequest)

        setTintColor(backButtonImageView, enabled: false)
        setTintColor(forwardButtonImageView, enabled: false)

    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    }

    override var preferredStatusBarStyle : UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        IHProgressHUD.dismiss()
    }

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()

        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        webView.navigationDelegate = self

        webView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(WKWebView.title), options: .new, context: nil)
        webView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(WKWebView.canGoForward), options: .new, context: nil)
        webView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(WKWebView.canGoBack), options: .new, context: nil)

        if (webView != nil) {
            mainView.addConstrained(subview: webView!)
        }
    }

    // MARK: WkWebview
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        IHProgressHUD.show()
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        IHProgressHUD.dismiss()
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFail navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
        IHProgressHUD.dismiss()
        BannerManager.errorLoadingWebpage.show()
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
        guard let failingUrlStr = (error as NSError).userInfo["NSErrorFailingURLStringKey"] as? String  else { return }
        let failingUrl = URL(string: failingUrlStr)!

        switch failingUrl {
            // Needed to open Appstore-App
            case _ where failingUrlStr.hasPrefix("itms-appss://"):
                if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(failingUrl) {
                    UIApplication.shared.open(failingUrl, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
                    IHProgressHUD.dismiss()
                    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                    return
                } else {
                    self.webView(webView, didFail: navigation, withError: error)
                }
            default: self.webView(webView, didFail: navigation, withError: error)
        }
    }

//    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView,
//                 decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction,
//                 decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
//        
//        // if the url is not http(s) schema, then the UIApplication open the url
//        if let url = navigationAction.request.url,
//            !url.absoluteString.hasPrefix("http://"),
//            !url.absoluteString.hasPrefix("https://"),
//            UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
//            
//            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
//            // cancel the request
//            decisionHandler(.cancel)
//        } else {
//            // allow the request
//            decisionHandler(.allow)
//        }
//    }

    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        if keyPath == "title" {
            self.primaryLabel.text = webView.title
            self.secondaryLabel.text = webView.url?.absoluteString
        } else if keyPath == "canGoBack" {
            setTintColor(backButtonImageView, enabled: webView.canGoBack)
        } else if keyPath == "canGoForward" {
            setTintColor(forwardButtonImageView, enabled: webView.canGoForward)
        }
    }

    // MARK: Private Funcs
    private func setTintColor(_ image:UIImageView, enabled:Bool) {
        image.tintColor = enabled ? UIColor.textSecondary : UIColor.ECHLightGrey
    }

    @objc func imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let tappedImage = tapGestureRecognizer.view as! UIImageView
        if tappedImage == backButtonImageView {
            webView.goBack()
        } else if tappedImage == forwardButtonImageView {
            webView.goForward()
        }
    }
}

extension WebPageModalViewController : UIScrollViewDelegate {

    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        scrollView.contentOffset.x = 0
    }
}
```

Any thoughts would be great!

Answer (score 2):

We have seen the same issue.

Our investigation suggests it started happening with the release of either iOS 13.4 or 13.4.1 (don't have a device with 13.4 on to verify this) but it works fine up to that point.

So far i haven't found a fix to the issue, but I do have a workaround.

What I observed is that this happens more often on slower networks and when the user interacts before a page is fully loaded. If the user taps back before the page has finished loading the error occurs. This error basically means "Cancelled" and references the page they are leaving. if they let the page load finish, obviously this error won't occur. Now importantly at this point the web view status is "Loading".

However, if the page they are returning to never finished loading at the point they left, then the error is thrown again, but this time referencing the page they are returning to. and more importantly the web view is no longer loading at this point.

what we have done is monitor this and check to see if the page is not loading, and if it isn't, reload it. This seems to work and while not ideal, its buying us some time to investigate a proper fix.

In addition, I put a retry limit on this and we show an error with a reload button after the third attempt, though in practice we've never seen it go beyond the first reload attempt.

The fact that the error is thrown almost instantaneously means the reload adds no perceivable delay for the user.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue in iOS 13.4, it's happening because WebView did finish loading is taking extra time in getting called.

use
`webView.stopLoading()`
just before

```
 if webView.canGoBack { 
    print("go back") 
    webView.goBack()
 }
```

its working for me

Comment: Excellent solution, works fine.  Used it within @objc func....  and linked it to code in my example:        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(goBack))